# how to add ubject to redis

Tags: node.js, redis

i have a sign up route

the request contains name,email,password

in the controller i have this code

```
user = {}
    user.rate = 0
    user.win = 0
    user.lose = 0
    user.numOfSub = 0
    user.online = true
    user.inFight = false
    user.notification = []
    user.friends = []
    user.sent_frined = []
    user.sent_noti = []
    user.image = ''
    user.uuid = ''
    user.name = req.body.name
    user.email = req.body.email
    user.password = req.body.password
    user.admin = req.body.admin
    let code = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999)

client.hmset(code, user, (err, reply) => {
        if (err)
            return res.status(404).json({
                msg: err,
                err: err.message
            })
    })
```

after this i tried to get the stored user

```
client.hgetall(code, (err,reply) => {
    console.log(reply);
})
```

but what i got was the things that came from the req.body only
such as

```
{
  name: 'abc',
  password: '123',
  email: 'email@email.com',
  admin: 'false'
}
```

and not all the data i entered
how to store the entire data in redis

Answer (score 0):

redis hash only accepts strings as key values. And you try to save arrays.
Redis doesn't support it.
You can store freeform object as stringified json in redis key.

```
const data = JSON.stringify(user);
client.set(code, data, function(err){....});
```

than, you can extract data from redis this way

```
redis.get(code, function(error, data){
  if(error) {
    throw error
  }
  const dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(data.parsed);
});
```